# Correct syntax for javax.servlet.annotation.ServletSecurity

Tags: servlets, java-ee-6, glassfish-3

Has anybody got a code sample for `javax.servlet.annotation.ServletSecurity` annotation.

I have had a look around but all I find are javadoc pages which won´t tell you how `javax.servlet.annotation.ServletSecurity` and `javax.servlet.annotation.HttpMethodConstraint` fit together and how a correct annotation should look like.

Answer (score 3):

How about [this example](http://vikaskumar9.blogspot.com/2011/02/ejb-31-security-example.html)?  It uses:

```
@ServletSecurity(
   @HttpConstraint(rolesAllowed = {"Authorized"})
)
```

Comment: So I got the it correct. Only my authentications still don't work. But wait, what is this: `@RolesAllowed({"Authorized"})`. That would qualify for „fit together“.